# ASP.NET - Use tracing to capture errors and send report back to ADMIN

Tags: asp.net, trace

I wanted to use tracing to capture errors and programmatically send reports via email and text message...that if the ADMIN is eating out at a restaurant on a saturday nite he can see the text message/email to notify and capture..any way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

A site that lets you essentially post exceptions to it, and then you can configure message in a number of ways.  I've not had a chance to use this much yet.  I think it's more popular w/ ruby, but because it's using standard HTTP posts, you should be able to use it from anything.
http://www.getexceptional.com/

For something more .net-specific, check out: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/
This will save a ton of information locally, and there is then a handler that exposes the data as an RSS feed.  From there, you should be able to find numerous ways to consume it.  This one I've used to great effect.

Comment: Ok Let me Check it.. Thanks a lot